# Determine most likely "divisor"

Tags: approximation, fractions

Given a sequence of samples $S$ I'd like to find $k$ given that most of the samples are known to be $h/k+\delta$ ($h$: random integer $[0,k]$, $\delta$: random noise). Unfortunately, I'm having trouble to come up with the right search terms to find a solution. Are there any approaches to find $k$?

#### Example (Python)

```
import random
k = 5
samples = [random.randint(0, k) / k + 0.01 * (random.random() - 0.5) for _ in range(100)]
samples += [random.random() for _ in range(10)] # outliers
random.shuffle(samples)
print(samples)
```

#### Update

In the meantime, I tried to interpret the samples as frequencies $f_i = S_i*f_k$ where $f_k = \frac{1}{k}$. However, I haven't been able to come up with a way to go further (Fourier transform?).

Comment: So, basically you want to approximate real values by "relatively simple" rational ones, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I'm looking for. Do I need to specify additional constraints on $k$?

Comment: In Matlab, see here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html . For python, see limit_denominator at the bottom of https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html . There should probably be more functions, and one might fit your needs. Just search for "approximate by fraction/rational" and the name of your favorite programming language.